# Rails is throwing an error the first time an attribute is assigned to my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a rails model that keeps track of other models in an app. (unusual, but necessary for this project).

When I try to assign the attribute `model_name` I get an error that occurs once, but then doesn't occur again.

```
AppModel
model_name   created_at   updated_at
----------------------------------------
User 
Question
Post
Answer
```

In console, I'm getting a strange error:

```
> model = AppModel.new
> model.model_name = "User"  # First time causes the error.
> model.model_name = "User"  # Second time it works.
```

**Error**:

```
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: record_changed? is defined by Active Record
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:104:in `instance_method_already_implemented?'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:288:in `block in define_attribute_method'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:285:in `each'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:285:in `define_attribute_method'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:252:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:252:in `each'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:252:in `define_attribute_methods'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:75:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mutex_m.rb:73:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mutex_m.rb:73:in `mu_synchronize'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:72:in `define_attribute_methods'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:196:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):3
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/Projects/hooker/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/donaldpinkus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.1.5 :004 > e.model_name = "User"
 => "User"
```

"model_name" isn't a reserved word for models, so what is happening here?

Comment: Do you have a column named 'record' in your table? That's a reserved word for ActiveRecord

Comment: It refers to `record_changed?`. Are you showing us everything in that table/model?

Comment: Can you show us how `model_name` is defined in the migration.

Comment: `model_name` IS a reserved word, so just name your column something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because there is already a method in ActiveRecord models, which is called exactly `model_name`, that returns (obviously) the name of this model (among other things).

> - **From:**
>     .../ruby-2.1.5/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/naming.rb
>     @ line 222:
> - **Owner:** ActiveModel::Naming
> - **Visibility:** public
> - **Signature:** model_name()
> - **Number of lines:** 12
>
> Returns an ActiveModel::Name object for module. It can be used to
>   retrieve all kinds of naming-related information (See
>   ActiveModel::Name for more information).

When ActiveRecord fetches an object from the table, it also creates methods with names corresponding to the column names in the table. What happens is it fetches an object, sees a column `model_name` on the given object, tries to define a method `model_name` and suddenly finds out that it already exists.

Here's a thing: avoid needlessly long attribute names. If you're defining a name in a model, it can just be `name`, it's scoped to "model" class anyway, obviously it's the model's name.

The error reporting code, however, likely contains a bug that needs to be tracked down.